# Selecting Dynamic date in a date range of sql

Tags: sql, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

This is what my query's date range is:

```
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN 20190101 AND [here date should come as last year YTD -1]
```

For example if we use this query **today** (20201106) (format:yyyymmdd), then the 2nd date should be `20191105`.

For more clarity: when I run this query **today** (20201106) my query should fetch results from date range:

```
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN 20190101 AND 20191105
```

When I run this query **tomorrow** (20201107), my query should fetch results from the date range:

```
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN 20190101 AND 20191106
```

How can I do this?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please, add tag of your database platform, because date functions are different in each DBMS. In general, you should look for date functions reference of your DBMS and find an appropriate function to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dateadd()` with `getdate()`

```
DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
```

or other function that can get current database time but this should work.
also remember to use `convert()` to modify the date format into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 
DATEADD(YEAR,-1, GETDATE()) -- One Day Before Today in the Last Year
AND 
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(YEAR,-1, GETDATE())), 0) AS StartOfYear -- The Day 1 of the Last Year
```

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as:

```
where date >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1)
  and date <  dateadd(year, -1, convert(date, getdate()))
```

This filters from the start of last year and the 1 year and 1 day ago.

Note that I changed the filtering strategy to use half-open intervals rather than `between`. This is somehow more flexible, as it would properly handle a time component in in `date`, if any, and simplifies the offsetting logic.

Note also that `getdate()` has a time component, that needs to be removed while offsetting to implement your logic.